# Solr WhitespaceTokenizerFactory will make URL parameter no work

Tags: search, solr, special-characters, highlight

I created a new field type as seen below:

```
<fieldType name="text_whitespace" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" rule="unicode" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" rule="unicode" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I need WhitespaceTokenizerFactory to make special characters to index and search, and it's working now,

But I have other question,
When I used WhitespaceTokenizerFactory, it will make URL parameter no work,

e.g. http://localhost:8983/solr/Test1/select?defType=dismax&hl.fl=content&hl=on&indent=on&q=%22C#"&qf=content^100&rows=1&wt=json

when I used that parameter in Solr Web UI,

It will work and get the result,

But When I used the URL and same parameter I get no result

and this is my date:

```
[
    {
     "id" : "test1",
     "title" : "test1# title C*?#",
     "content" : "test1# title C*?#",
     "dynamic_s": 5
    },
    {
     "id" : "test2",
     "title" : "test2 title C#",
     "content" : "test2 title C#",
     "dynamic_s": 10
    },
    {
     "id" : "test3",
     "title" : "test3 title",
     "content" : "test3 title",
     "dynamic_s": 0
    }
]
```

If I use WhitespaceTokenizerFactory how do I make the parameter work in URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to Solr, but is how HTTP works.

As explained in your original post, this is because `#` has special meaning in HTTP URLs. A `#` indicates a local anchor, and is never transmitted to the server - it's used to keep a local reference to a single point in the page (these days the value behind `#` refers to the `id` of the element the page should scroll to when being displayed, but earlier it referenced an empty `a` tag with a name).

To use characters with special meaning in URLs (`&` would also mean that there's a new parameter coming instead of being interpreted as a value to an argument), you have to escape them. In Javascript you can use `encodeURIComponent` to do this:

```
encodeURIComponent("foo#&bar")
-> "foo%23%26bar"
```

So to send the value `foo#&bar` as the argument, and not introduce a new parameter or a local anchor hash, the value would be sent as `foo%23%26bar` instead. Your HTTP server will decode this for you automagically.

```
?q=field%3Afoo%23%26bar
```

.. will be interpreted as `field:foo#&bar` serverside. Since ':' can usually be used safely in URLs, you don't have to escape it - but it doesn't hurt to do it properly. Look up URL escaping in your language of choice if you're going to do this in an application.